# Validate password - must contain 2 capital letters

Tags: javascript, validation, passwords

Can someone tell me why this function doesn't work? the password length and the check of number work perfectly. But it is something wrong with the check of big capitals...

```
function validera() {
var passw = document.getElementById("User-Password").value;
var upper = /[A-Z]/ ;
var number = /[0-9]/;

if (passw.length < 6 || !number.test(passw) || !upper.test(passw)) {
    if (passw.length < 6) {
        alert("Please make sure password is longer than 6 characters.")
        return false;
    }

    var counter = 0;
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < passw.length; i++){
       passw.charAt(i)
       if(upper.test(passw.charAt(i))){
           counter++;
           break;
       }
   }

    if( counter < 2 ){
        alert("Please make sure password includes 2 capital letters")
        return false;

    }

    if (!number.test(passw)) {
        alert("Please make sure Password Includes a Digit")
        return false;
    }

} else {
    alert("Account created")
}
```

Or do I have to use regex?

Comment: Your `break` statement breaks the loop as soon as you encounter the first capital letter. So, your counter will always be 1.

Comment: Why loop when 1 regex test would do ?  `if(!/[A-Z].*[A-Z]/.test(passw)){alert('Cap me twice!');return false;}`

Comment: Still doesn't work? 
 if(!/[A-Z].*[A-Z]/.test(passw))
        {alert('Cap me twice!')
        ;return false;}

is it just like that? i have never used regex before

Comment: I can still write "test1A"

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use regex to find two capital letters then you can use like

```
\w*[A-Z]\w*[A-Z]\w*
```

Test this [here](https://www.regextester.com/114052) on regextester

Answer (score 0):

Here Check it out [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RaviMakwana/tq6xwea2/)

```
CreateRandomPassword(Length, isUpperAlpha, isLowerAlpha, isNumaric ,SpecialChars)
```

I have developed easy function to generate password

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that returns an object with a message and a boolean.

**Example snippet:**

```js
function testPassword(pwd) {

   if (pwd.length <= 6) 
        return { valid: false, message: "Please make sure password is longer than 6 characters." };
    
   if(!/[A-Z].*[A-Z]/.test(pwd))
        return { valid: false, message: "Please make sure password includes 2 capital letters" };

   if (!/\d/.test(pwd)) 
        return { valid: false, message: "Please make sure Password Includes a Digit" };

   if (/\s/.test(pwd)) 
        return { valid: false, message: "Please only use visible characters" };

   return { valid: true, message: "Valid Password" };
}
 
console.log(testPassword('Val1dPassword')); 
console.log(testPassword('SH0rt')); 
console.log(testPassword('No2capitals')); 
console.log(testPassword('NoDigits'));
console.log(testPassword('Has\tat least 1 WhiteSpace'));
```

Then your function can be simplified.

```
function validera() {
    let passw = document.getElementById("User-Password").value;
    let check = testPassword(passwd);
    if (check.valid) {
        alert(check.message);
        return false;
    }
     else {
        alert("Account created")
    }
  }
```